# Pass parameters from jenkins pipeline to downstream pipeline type job , each job having separate Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs, each of pipeline type with separate jenkinsfile for each of them. How can i pass a string parameter from one job to another. Every job launches it's own docker container, because of which once the build is finished the workspace is wiped off(or no more available). The content of ReportLog.txt should be available to the next job.The reportLog.txt content is being printed in the current job's console logs.
jenkinfile snippet:

```
def PARAM=''
    stage("Checkout") {
        scmCheckout {
            deleteWorkspace = 'true'
            println "Clean checkout"

        }
    }
          stage('Set variables') {  
            println "Reading text file"
            def x = "${WORKSPACE}/ReportLog.txt"
            PARAMS = readFile(x)
            println PARAMS

    }



}
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you use the snippet generator yet? It'll tell you how to do this.

Comment: Yes I tried snippet generator. I want to pass params in between pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following steps in the snippet generator:

```
properties
```

To define the parameters for the jobs which you actually want to trigger - if you do not want to define it using the UI.

```
build
```

To build those jobs. The `build` step will also allow you to define the parameters to pass to the other jobs.

To pass the content of a file you could read that file into a `String` using the `readFile` step - what you already did.